# Replace entire line in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am using the replace module to replace an entire line in Ansible.  The line contains double and single quotes.  I have tried to add "\\" to escape them, but it doesn't seem to work. Could someone help me with the correct syntax?  The actual line in the file is set by default to

```
<!-- <param name="core-db-dsn" value="pgsql://hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=freeswitch user=freeswitch password='' options='-c client_min_messages=NOTICE'" /> -->
```

I need to uncomment it out and replace the db sections with Postgres DB-info variable.

```
- name: "Update switch.conf.xml with Postgres DB info"
  replace:
    path: /etc/freeswitch/autoload_configs/switch.conf.xml
    regexp: '^<!-- <param name="core-db-dsn" value="pgsql: .*$'
    line: "<param name="core-db-dsn" value="pgsql://hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname={{ DB-Info }} user={{ DB-Info
              }} password='{{ DB-Pass }}' options='-c client_min_messages=NOTICE'" />"
```

Comment: 'DB-Pass ' and 'DB-Info' are not valid variables. Replace the dash '-' with underscore '_'.

Comment: The module 'replace' will replace all occurrences of 'regexp' in the file. If this is not what you want use 'lineinfile' instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are more options. To avoid escaping complex expressions, put them into the files. For example, put the regex and the lines into the (r*,l*) set of files

```bsh
shell> cat files/replace/r1 
^<!-- <param name="core-db-dsn" value="pgsql:(.*)$
```

```bsh
shell> cat files/replace/l1 
<param name="core-db-dsn" value="pgsql://hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname={{ DB_Info }} user={{ DB_Info }} password='{{ DB_Pass }}' options='-c client_min_messages=NOTICE'" />
```

Then the task below does the job

```yaml
  - replace:
      path: switch.conf.xml
      regexp: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/replace/r1') }}"
      replace: "{{ lookup('template', 'files/replace/l1') }}"
    vars:
      DB_Info: freeswitch2
      DB_Pass: passwd
```

---

If there are more files run the task in the loop. For example

```yaml
  - replace:
      path: switch.conf.xml
      regexp: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/replace/r' ~ ansible_loop.index ) }}"
      replace: "{{ lookup('template', 'files/replace/l' ~ ansible_loop.index) }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', 'files/replace/r*', wantlist=True) }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
    vars:
      DB_Info: freeswitch2
      DB_Pass: passwd
```

Make sure the 'glob' matches only what you want. Delete any temporary or backup files. The loop expects a set of (r*,l*) files with the continuous index starting from 1.

---

To avoid the maintenance of too many (r*,l*) files, put all the regex and lines into single files and loop the lines of the files. For example

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: switch.conf.xml
        regexp: "{{ item.0 }}"
        replace: "{{ item.1 }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ lookup('file', 'files/replace/r-all').splitlines() }}"
        - "{{ lookup('template', 'files/replace/l-all').splitlines() }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.0 }}"
      vars:
        DB_Info: freeswitch2
        DB_Pass: passwd
```